# jQuery countdown Keith Wood not working in mozilla

Tags: jquery, firefox, countdown

I am working on a site and I've installed Keiths Woods's jQuery countdown. It's working perfectly on Chrome but in IE, Mozilla, iPad, and iPhones it does not work.
The count down counts perfectly until 10.1.2012. It shows 72 days, 7 hours and so on. On other browsers it shows `NaN` days, `NaN` hours and so on.

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.countdown.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="countdown"></div>
        <div class="logo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside `scripts.js` I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date = new Date('10.1.2012'); 
    $('.countdown').countdown({until: date , format: 'DHMS'}); 
});
```

What is wrong with `jquery.countdown.min.js`? I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Anyone ? Help is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uncapping the `D` to `d`:

```
$('.countdown').countdown({until: date , format: 'dHMS'});
```

Because the same is done on the [homepage of the plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html):

```
$(selector).countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'dHM'});
```

Edit: Change to the following, [it works for me in Safari](http://jsfiddle.net/Calavoow/jZSAq/3/):

```
var date = new Date(2012, 10-1, 1);
```

The parsing of the string probably went wrong in browsers other than Chrome.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you ! So kind of you to help.

Answer (score 3):

Check your date.
If your your date is ex. "02-23-2012 23:22:22"
change it to "02/23/2012 23:22:22"

Use forward slashes or else iphone mozilla will complain

Comment: Thanks, this was it for my version of this problem.